# IE growing letter on home page

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, internet-explorer

I have a wordpress site with a plugin container. In the container there are 3 widgets, with the same code. It looks good on ff and chrome, but in IE, every letter is bigger that the previous one. Is this due to some invalid CSS?

Comment: Could you post a link, some code, a screenshot, or a combination of the three?

Comment: That doesn't sounds like something you could do unintentionally with CSS. Can you post a link or some html/css code?

Comment: here is the link: http://networkednews.net/

Comment: Wow, that is interesting. I'm looking things over, but sof ar I'm starting to think it has to do with your using a % for font-size

Comment: I just visited your site with IE9 - got an error "unable to get value of the property 'style':object is null or undefined in googleCards.min.js

Comment: Better to use `pt` unit for font size.

Comment: Yeah, don't use % size. Still, can't find what is making the objects get bigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your markup. I don't think the first H4 is closed properly causing all elements below to inherit from the opening H4.

```
<div class='title'>
 <h4>
  <a href="http://social-media.networkednews.net/uncategorized/this-website-will-start-soon-only-in-a-few-days/2011/11/30" target="_blank"> This website will start soon, only in a few days!</a>
 <h4>  <!--- Here --->
</div>
<i>30 Nov 2011, 09:01</i>
```

Edit: Seems all of them are missing the closing `</H4>` in my IE9

Comment: FF/WebKit are smart enough to catch this. IE is dumb. Good call.